# Finding a Polynomial Time algorithm for the 3-SAT Problem

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np-hard, np, satisfiability

Let us consider m clauses containing 3 variables each i.e. **A<sub>1</sub>**,**A<sub>2</sub>**,**A<sub>3</sub>**...**A<sub>m</sub>** . Let the total literals in consideration be n. Then each clause :

**A<sub>i</sub>** = (**x<sub>r</sub>** $\lor$ **x<sub>s</sub>** $\lor$ **x<sub>t</sub>**)

where 1 $\le$ r,s,t $\le$n and each literal can take a boolean value or its negation. Our expression $\phi$ which we need to satisfy hence looks as follows :

$\phi$ = (**A<sub>1</sub>** $\land$ **A<sub>2</sub>** $\land$ **A<sub>3</sub>** $\land$ .... **A<sub>m</sub>**)

---

We now define an array B where each index stores sets of n tuples which are defined later. We now begin with the procedure. Assign all the boolean literals **x<sub>1</sub>**, **x<sub>2</sub>**, **x<sub>3</sub>** .... **x<sub>n</sub>** as true and evaluate $\phi$.

1. If $\phi$ is true, we are done. Else initialize i=1 and set B[1]={(-1,-1,.....-1)} such that B[1] is a set of a n-tuple.
2. Evaluate **A<sub>i</sub>** by trying all 8 combinations of assignments for the 3 literals. One of these assignments will make **A<sub>i</sub>** false. Consider **A<sub>i</sub>** = (**x<sub>r</sub>** $\lor$ **x<sub>s</sub>** $\lor$ **x<sub>t</sub>**) . Set the r,s and t the element in the tuple at B[i] as 0 or 1 as per the assignment that makes the clause false. If i is equal to 1, go to step 2.
3. Perform a merge operation between B[i-1] and B[i]. For each element in B[i-1], compare it with the only element in B[i] at coordinates where neither elements contain -1. For example if we have to merge the tuples (0,0,-1,0) and (-1,0,0,1), we ignore coordinates 1 and 3. We compare the remaining coordinates i.e. 2 and 4. If among the remaining coordinates, **they ONLY differ at 1 position**, then $\phi$ is unsatisfiable. Else if for all elements in B[i-1], we find no such condition with the element in B[i], we add all elements from B[i-1] to B[i] .
4. Increment i by 1, If i=m i.e. we have evaluated all clauses, goto Step 5. Else Go back to step 2.
5. $\phi$ is satisfiable (exit)

I am an undergraduate student and I was trying to see why the 3-SAT problem was NP-hard. Is this a valid way to evaluate if $\phi$ is satisfiable or not in polynomial time? Or have I gone wrong somewhere?

Comment: I can believe that this detects some unsatisfiable formulas, but can you give an argument why this is a *complete* procedure? (ie definitely detects satisfiability)

Comment: I am unsure of proving it formally and will try it out. At the moment, its just a theorization I have

Comment: does B[m] begin with one n-tuple (-1,...-1) ? And every iteration it can have up to 8 more assignments (n-tuples) added to it? And the algorithm ends if the size of B[m] = $2^n$? Is this correct?

Comment: B[i] begins with one n-tuple . For 3 literals in each clause, there will exist only one assignment which doesn't satisfy it. So we add only one of the assignments after checking all 8. The algorithm ends if i is equal to m or if the condition in bold holds true

Comment: I suggest you try implementing it, pick a test suite of example CNF formulas (e.g., from a SAT solver competition), and compare its output to an existing known-good SAT solver on each of those test cases.  If you find any input where it gives the wrong output, you know that this is not a correct algorithm.  That will also let you compare the running time of your algorithm to those of existing SAT solvers.

Comment: @Pathlessbark8 so[i] begins with one n-tuple and you add one assignment to it at a time, and it asserts unsatisfiability if the sizeOf(B[i]) = $2^n$ and so wouldn't your runtime necessarily be exponential (and not a polytime algorithm as you claim?)

Comment: I am sorry, I meant B[i]=n . I will rectify that, thank you for pointing it out

Comment: As a rule of thumb, amateur mathematicians rarely break well established results.